# How to copy files from 'assets' to system in the rooted android device?

Tags: android, copy, system, rooted-device

I want to do it.But i got  /system/app/filename: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system) error.

Comment: `Read-only file system` means that you have to remount system as read-write.

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su mount -o remount,rw /system/media/");

Comment: It dose not work.

Comment: `It dose not work` - how exactly? what is the output? the error?

Comment: FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(“/system/media/bootanimation.zip”);---> /system/app/bootanimation.zip: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system) error.

Comment: what is the output of `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su mount -o remount,rw /system/media/");`

Comment: Process  process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
            os.writeBytes(" mount -o remount,rw /system/media/" + "\n");
            os.writeBytes("exit\n");
            os.flush();
            process.waitFor();//   process.waitFor()=1

Comment: It's rooted device.Why?

Answer (score -1):

This is an example. Please try

```
private void saveFileToInternal(String orginal_url) {
        File file = new File(orginal_url);
        File dir = mContext.getDir(TEMP_FOLDER, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        File dest = new File(dir, "filename_" + file.getName());
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Can not create file", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you always want to thumb down all answers from other user. Right?

Comment: no, only the answers, that don't relate to the question.